# Sort list without reloading iframe

Tags: javascript

How can I sort the list without realoading the iframe inside the li? (appendChild makes the iframe reload)

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var my_ul = document.getElementById('my_ul'),
        my_button = document.getElementById('my_button');

    function sort_function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
            my_ul.appendChild(document.querySelector('[data-sort="' + list[i] + '"]'));
        }
    }

    my_button.onclick = function () {
        sort_function();
    }

}
</script>

<a id=my_button href="#">Sort</a>
<ul id=my_ul>
    <li data-sort=3>3<iframe src="#3"></iframe>
    <li data-sort=2>2<iframe src="#2"></iframe>
    <li data-sort=4>4<iframe src="#4"></iframe>
    <li data-sort=1>1<iframe src="#1"></iframe>
    <li data-sort=5>5<iframe src="#5"></iframe>
</ul>
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434230/how-to-prevent-an-iframe-from-reloading-when-moving-it-in-the-dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move an object in the DOM, it will get removed and re-appended. The result is that the contents of the `iframe` will be reloaded.

I don't know what you're showing in those iframes, but maybe you can get rid of them and load the content dynamically using AJAX (f.e. [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)).

If you really want to use `iframe` and you really want to avoid reloading them, I think the only way is to make the `li` elements floating and to reposition them dynamically.

I've created a [jsFiddle that demonstrates this](http://jsfiddle.net/guYtj/2/). The code uses jQuery.

**HTML**

*Close the li tags*

```
<a id="my_button" href="#">Sort</a>
<ul id="my_ul">
    <li data-sort=3>3<iframe src="#3"></iframe></li>
    <li data-sort=2>2<iframe src="#2"></iframe></li>
    <li data-sort=4>4<iframe src="#4"></iframe></li>
    <li data-sort=1>1<iframe src="#1"></iframe></li>
    <li data-sort=5>5<iframe src="#5"></iframe></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

*Use absolute positioning for li elements*

```
#my_ul li {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var iframeTop = 0;

// Initial positioning at document load
$(function() {
    var ofsTop = $("#my_ul li:first-child").position().top;
    $("#my_ul li").each(function(index, value) {
        $(value).css({ top: ofsTop + 'px'});
        ofsTop += $(value).height();
    });
});

// Re-position when user clicks #my_button
$("#my_button").click(function() {
    // sort li depending on data-sort
    var sorted = $("#my_ul li").sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).data("sort") - $(b).data("sort");
    });
    // re-position li's
    if (!iframeTop) iframeTop = $("#my_ul li:first-child").position().top;
    var ofsTop = iframeTop;
    $.each(sorted, function(index, value) {
        $(value).css({ top: ofsTop + 'px'});
        ofsTop += $(value).height();
    });
});
```