# jQuery appending iframe to div without reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

```
$("#div").append('<iframe width="200" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zoMYU_nOGNg?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>');
```

By using this example `append` cause page reload, maybe are some issue to load youtube iframe without reloading page

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/0uqtn0u5/

My observation is wrong it's not realod the page.

Comment: What triggers the call?

Comment: Your posted code doesn't reload the page but the iframe. Is it your issue???

Comment: @A.Wolff page reloads - same as press F5

Comment: So something else refreshs it or your observation is wrong. If you think all page is refreshed because of browser loading icon is animated, that not means all the page is refreshed but in this case just that some page element is loading

Comment: $("#div").append('<iframe id="youtube" width="200" height="100" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>');

    $("#youtube").src = https://www.youtube.com/embed/zoMYU_nOGNg?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;enablejsapi=1'

Comment: @A.Wolff take a look in my jsfiddle example

Comment: Change `<button>` to `<button type="button">` - some browsers will submit the page when a button is clicked.

Comment: @mplungjan is not matter

Comment: @Wizard So ya, your observation is wrong, see: https://jsfiddle.net/0uqtn0u5/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some browsers will treat `<button>` as a submit button and submit to the same page regardless of the button being a child of a form or not.

Change to

```
$('button').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#youtube").append('<iframe width="200" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zoMYU_nOGNg?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>');
});
```

or add `type="button"` to it.

If you DO have a form, instead do make the button a submit button and prevent the default action on the form submit:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#youtube").append('<iframe width="200" height="100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zoMYU_nOGNg?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>');
});
```

There is no other reason for the page to reload. Your code should not and indeed does not reload anything in Chrome

Comment: I think you pointed the right thing, OP was submiting a form i guess. But that's wrong: `submit to the same page regardless of the button being a child of a form or not`

Comment: @wizard: did it solve the problem, or is the page not actually reloading?

Comment: @mplungjan If you check OP jsfiddle, it is clear his observation is wrong, the page isn't reloaded

Comment: @A.Wolff - I agree. It will not reload in most browsers and indeed does not reload in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

**Take a look:** [How to prevent an iframe from reloading when moving it in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434230/how-to-prevent-an-iframe-from-reloading-when-moving-it-in-the-dom)

"If you're trying to move it visually, you can try modifying the CSS to use absolute positioning or some other adjustments.

However, if you're trying to actually pull it out of the DOM and insert it somewhere else, you won't be able to avoid a reload."

~ John Fisher

**Also:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8318401/5444802

"It isn't possible to move an iframe from one place in the dom to another without it reloading."

~ Kevin B

Answer (score 0):

Check the youtube api for iframe embedding 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player