# jQuery modal pop-up doesn't pick up the values in click handler

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using the [Basic Modal Dialog](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/) in my ASP.NET web application. In the `pageload` event handler, it correctly binds the data to the text boxes which are inside the modal popup. But when I try to retrieve the values from the text boxes in the `buttonclick` event handler, it just returns empty strings as the value.

The code is basically like this have text boxes inside a div which pop-up:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="fname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

In pageload:

```
fname.Text = customer.firstName; this is working
```

In button click:

```
protected void BtnSaveinfoClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var firstname = fname.Text.Trim();// this taking values as ""
}
```

I did make a `breakpoint` in the `buttonclick`. when i hover over the `fname` text box with the `firebug` it showing me the value is there.

```
<input id="MainContent_cphMain_PersonalInfo1_fname" type="text" value="Andrew" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$cphMain$PersonalInfo1$fname">
```

Any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: Can you provide some source code, cut down if necessary, to illustrate the problem as best as possible?

Comment: i just added basic code to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what happenes [Fix your postbacks in Modal forms](http://lawo.wordpress.com/2009/03/18/jquery-modal-forms-break-aspnet-postback-functionality/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [`appendTo` option](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) to append the dialog to the form for ASP.NET events to fire:

**appendTo [String:'body']**

The jQuery selector to append the elements to. For ASP.NET, use 'form'.

NOTE: jQuery UI Dialogs get appended the to the body tag by default.  All .NET controls must be rendered inside the form tag to work properly.  For an exercise, try adding any control(ie: asp:textbox) to a page that has runat="server", outside of the form tag and see what ASP.NET has to say about it.

Comment: Could be the reason, though the question does seem to suggest the event is firing but that fname is empty.

Comment: They said buttonclick did not fire.

Comment: this is correct. this pop-up is inside a WebUserControler. the page structure is Masterpage -> sub masterpage -> .aspx page -> controler(with the pop up). When i looked at the page source in runtime it appear that the popup is outside the form tag and inside the body

Comment: Rick, fair enough, didn't post that. Oddly enough, answered a question on this just yesterday :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672890/aspbutton-click-event-is-not-firing/7673768#7673768

Comment: Yeah, since the user is using a wrapper plug-in for the dialog, although the same issue, the solution a tad different.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked through your Page_Load and other scripts to make sure that you are not clearing `fname` at any point before it reaches the event?

Comment: I checked that but it dosen't