# jquery causes asp.net button to not click

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I can't get the OnClick method for the button to fire

The button:

```
<asp:Button ID="postButton" runat="server" 
   Text="Create Thread" OnClick="postButton_Click" />
```

**EDIT: postButton_Click is a code behind(server side) C#**

After a bit of trial and error i found out that the button does fire when the following line is removed:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"  
   type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The scripts are loaded in this order:

```
<link href="../ajax/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" 
   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" 
   type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../ajax/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js" 
   type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Changing the jQuery version does not help.

I have the exact same code on another page and it works fine. why does it happen and how can I fix it?

**EDIT: Codebehind (breakpoints set in this method fail to trigger)**

```
protected void postButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("test.aspx");
}
```

Comment: what code you have tried.?

Comment: any error in the console

Comment: are you using script manager ??

Comment: postButton_Click is server-side method or JavaScript function?

Comment: its a server-side method

Comment: show your server side method. are they matching the function declaration ?

Comment: Edited the question to include the codebehind method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so i finally found a fix for this problem

The reason that being that the ASP button was inside a JQuery UI dialog. When you use JQuery UI's Dialog plugin to bring up a div as a dialog, it usually pulls the div out of the form to do this and then ASP.Net elements don't work.

**Solution which worked:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7673768/1753000

Comment: you must have describe the question and scenario